# Elastic search by external id from other type

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search by external id from other type in single request.
Can i do this?

For example:
Two types in single index.
1. matrix - contain name and several products_id's in object

```
root@401488a854ac:/usr/share/elasticsearch# curl 'localhost:9200/ta/products/1?pretty'
{
  "_index" : "ta",
  "_type" : "products",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1100,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "@timestamp" : "2016-12-21T11:08:00.443Z",
    "componentsNested" : [
      {
        "amount" : 992,
        "component_id" : 92
      },
      {
        "amount" : 162,
        "component_id" : 35
      },
      {
        "amount" : 551,
        "component_id" : 57
      },
      {
        "amount" : 96,
        "component_id" : 28
      },
      {
        "amount" : 520,
        "component_id" : 92
      },
      {
        "amount" : 834,
        "component_id" : 75
      },
      {
        "amount" : 265,
        "component_id" : 87
      },
      {
        "amount" : 520,
        "component_id" : 86
      },
      {
        "amount" : 558,
        "component_id" : 12
      },
      {
        "amount" : 426,
        "component_id" : 19
      },
      {
        "amount" : 22,
        "component_id" : 6
      },
      {
        "amount" : 955,
        "component_id" : 79
      },
      {
        "amount" : 93,
        "component_id" : 50
      },
      {
        "amount" : 113,
        "component_id" : 99
      },
      {
        "amount" : 617,
        "component_id" : 53
      },
      {
        "amount" : 542,
        "component_id" : 64
      }
    ],
    "name" : "eveniet",
    "@version" : "1",
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "products",
    "tags" : [ ]
  }
}

root@401488a854ac:/usr/share/elasticsearch# curl 'localhost:9200/ta/matrix/1?pretty'
{
  "_index" : "ta",
  "_type" : "matrix",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1101,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "productsNested" : [
      {
        "cost" : 643,
        "product_id" : 62
      },
      {
        "cost" : 599,
        "product_id" : 13
      },
      {
        "cost" : 268,
        "product_id" : 22
      },
      {
        "cost" : 638,
        "product_id" : 73
      },
      {
        "cost" : 782,
        "product_id" : 94
      },
      {
        "cost" : 84,
        "product_id" : 46
      },
      {
        "cost" : 170,
        "product_id" : 49
      },
      {
        "cost" : 172,
        "product_id" : 16
      },
      {
        "cost" : 765,
        "product_id" : 36
      },
      {
        "cost" : 386,
        "product_id" : 85
      },
      {
        "cost" : 896,
        "product_id" : 62
      },
      {
        "cost" : 248,
        "product_id" : 71
      },
      {
        "cost" : 267,
        "product_id" : 48
      },
      {
        "cost" : 40,
        "product_id" : 90
      },
      {
        "cost" : 506,
        "product_id" : 63
      },
      {
        "cost" : 307,
        "product_id" : 15
      },
      {
        "cost" : 731,
        "product_id" : 74
      },
      {
        "cost" : 23,
        "product_id" : 71
      },
      {
        "cost" : 214,
        "product_id" : 93
      },
      {
        "cost" : 316,
        "product_id" : 48
      },
      {
        "cost" : 449,
        "product_id" : 100
      },
      {
        "cost" : 413,
        "product_id" : 30
      },
      {
        "cost" : 476,
        "product_id" : 91
      },
      {
        "cost" : 482,
        "product_id" : 73
      },
      {
        "cost" : 238,
        "product_id" : 19
      },
      {
        "cost" : 75,
        "product_id" : 21
      },
      {
        "cost" : 712,
        "product_id" : 32
      },
      {
        "cost" : 577,
        "product_id" : 8
      }
    ],
    "@timestamp" : "2016-12-21T11:09:00.251Z",
    "@version" : "1",
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "matrix",
    "tags" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I can search on it without problems.

2. products. Simple type with data.
   I can query:

> curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ta/products,matrix/_search?pretty' -d ' {
>     "query" : {         "terms": {
>           "_type": [ "products", "matrix" ]         }   },
>       "aggs": {
>         "types": {
>           "terms": {
>             "field": "_type", 
>             "size": 10
>           },        "aggs" : {          "ids" : {
>                 "terms" : {
>                     "field": "id"
>                 }           }       }
>        }   } }'

With correct result.
How i can query by matrix name for product_ids and find this documents in single request?

Comment: Can you post real example of data ? because I dont understand. document you posted with name and array is not valid json.

Comment: i was update data.